# Duplicated script not showing result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

This is my first question here, so pardon the naiveness please, thx.
I am currently building a calculator based on HTML, JS (+jQuery) and CSS. My calculator is a multi-input calculator that can count various things on a single webpage. For context, the calculator that I am building at the moment, is a gear calculator. It supposed to be able to calculate various items using various formulas. For the first item, it will be capable to calculate the module of a gear. This first calculation was successful with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
var valZ = parseInt($('.jumlahGigi').val());
var valD = parseInt($('.diameterPitch').val());
var sum = valD/valZ;
$("input#resultModule").val(sum);
});
});
```

I duplicate the script to calculate other items but I don't forget to change the variables. This is the next script to calculate the amount of teeth on a gear:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
  var valM = parseInt($('.module').val());
  var valD = parseInt($('.diameterPitch').val());
          var sum = valD/valM;
          $("input#resultAot").val(sum);
});
});
```

and this is the last script I wrote to calculate the diameter pitch:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
  var valM = parseInt($('.module').val());
  var valZ = parseInt($('.jumlahGigi').val());
          var sum = valZ*valM;
          $("input#resultDP").val(sum);
});
});
```

For the first item calculation, when I enter a number onto the input form, the result came out successfully. But for the other 2 calculations, the result won't came out. Can anyone maybe spot where my flaw lies?

Comment: And you probably do not want to do the calculations on each "keyup" event. Would be better to use the ["change" event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) as that would allow the user to finish typing a value before attempting to do the calculation.

Comment: @imvain2 maybe you want to take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ArDam/v7h023od/2/ . Im a beginner to jQuery, so i apologize for basic mistake I mightve done

Comment: From your fiddle, the issue is that you have multiple elements with the same class - 2 of each.  When your code does `$(".diameter").val()` - the `.val()` function takes the value from the *first* matching element, essentially `$(".diameter").first().val()` but for the 2nd calc you want it from the 2nd.  Either only have one input for all the calculations or give them different classes for each calc.  https://jsfiddle.net/56aetwyb/

Comment: @imvain2 "*adding all 3 of these keyup events to the page at the same time? if so, you are overwriting each time.*" - that's not how *events* work - that's how function definitions work, but each event is added as a *new* event handler - so all 3 run.  There's no "overwriting of events"  (can't believe that comment got any upvotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `$('.class').val()` will take the value only from the *first* matching element, essentially `$('.class').first().val()`.

In your fiddle, you have 2 of each input:  `.module`, `.diameter`, `.jumlahGigi`.

Your calculations are working fine, but they are taking values from earlier inputs - eg diameter pitch takes teeth from module and module from the teeth input.

The easiest option is to use unique classes for each input.

```js
//module
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var valZ = parseInt($('.moduleJumlahGigi').val());
    var valD = parseInt($('.moduleDiameterPitch').val());
    var sum = valD / valZ;
    $("input#resultModule").val(sum);
  });
});

//Amount of teeth
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var valM = parseInt($('.aotModule').val());
    var valD = parseInt($('.aotDiameterPitch').val());
    var sum = valD / valM;
    $("input#resultAot").val(sum);
  });
});

//Diameter Pitch
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var valM = parseInt($('.diameterModule').val());
    var valZ = parseInt($('.diameterJumlahGigi').val());
    var sum = valZ * valM;
    $("input#resultDP").val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="general">
  <div class="module">
    <label class="label"> Module </label>
    <input type="text" class="moduleDiameterPitch" placeholder="Diameter Pitch">
    <input type="text" class="moduleJumlahGigi" placeholder="Amount of Teeth">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="resultModule" placeholder="Module">
  </div>
  <div class="AoT">
    <label class="label"> Amount of Teeth </label>
    <input type="text" class="aotDiameterPitch" placeholder="Diameter Pitch">
    <input type="text" class="aotModule" placeholder="Module">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="resultAot" placeholder="Amount of Teeth">
  </div>
  <div class="diameterPitch">
    <label class="label">
      Diameter Pitch
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="diameterJumlahGigi" placeholder="Amount of Teeth">
    <input type="text" class="diameterModule" placeholder="Module">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Diameter Pitch" disabled="disabled" id="resultDP">
  </div>
</div>
```

The alternative is to use relative DOM navigation (`$(this).closest(".calc").find(".module")` - but as the calculations are very specific, it makes sense to name the inputs specifically for each calc.